# Match newline character in cpp-peglib

Tags: newline, grammar, peg

So I try to match single line comments in C++ using cpp-peglib. A comment starts with a # character followed by any sequence of characters and is terminated by the newline character. I tried different ways but with no success. It seems as if the parser cannot match the newline character, either my grammar is wrong or the newline characters in my string get somehow removed.

Here is a small example to get you started

```
std::string text = "# this is a comment\n # this is another comment";

// define grammar
auto grammar = R"(
    Start       <- (Comment)*
    Comment     <- '#' .+ EOL
    EOL         <- [\r\n]
)";

// setup parser
peg::parser parser;
parser.log = [](size_t line, size_t col, const std::string& msg) {
    std::cerr << line << ":" << col << ": " << msg << "\n";
};
auto ok = parser.load_grammar(grammar);
assert(ok);

// define parser rules
parser["Comment"] = [](const peg::SemanticValues& sv) {
    std::cout << "Comment: '" << sv.token()  << "'" << std::endl;
};

// parse file
parser.parse(text.c_str());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply. The following code works for me. Hope it helps.

```
// define grammar
auto grammar = R"(
    Start        <-  Comment*
    Comment      <-  [ \t\r\n]+ / LineComment
    LineComment  <-  '#' (!LineEnd .)* &LineEnd
    LineEnd      <-  '\r\n' / '\r' / '\n' / !.
)";
```

Comment: Cool thank you, I will try it out when I find some time.

Comment: Ok, I found some time to integrate it into my code and it works. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What does the `&` in the `LineComment` rule mean? Thanks.

Comment: `LineComment` is just a user defined rule. `&` is 'And-predicate` operator described well in the section 2 of original Bryan Ford's paper. https://bford.info/pub/lang/peg.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reply. @yhirose, I was not noticed the reply until today. Sorry for the late response.